# alter table column does not create

Tags: android

I did ALTER TABLE in my SQLite database, now updating my application everything is going well, but if you launch the new APK without having installed the old version of the database does not create the new column! Why?
this is the code I'm using:

```
 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

       if (newVersion >=2) {  
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Giornate ADD COLUMN note TEXT");  
       }  
}
```

in my helper class there are several tables in the "Giornate" I have to add the "NOTE" field

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    BilancioHelper.db = db;

    //tabella giornate
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("CREATE TABLE {0} (");
    builder.append("{1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
    builder.append("{2} TEXT,");
    builder.append("{3} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
    builder.append("{4} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
    builder.append("{5} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
    builder.append("{6} INTEGER,"); // E' boolean
    builder.append("{7} INTEGER"); // E' boolean
    builder.append(");");

    db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(builder.toString(),
            GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME, GiornateTable._ID,
            GiornateTable.DATA, GiornateTable.ENTRATA,
            GiornateTable.USCITA, GiornateTable.BANCA, GiornateTable.RIPOSO, GiornateTable.SPESA));
```

strings

```
public interface GiornateTable extends BaseColumns {

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Giornate";


public static final String ENTRATA = "entrata";
public static final String DATA = "data";
public static final String USCITA = "uscita";
public static final String BANCA = "banca";
public static final String RIPOSO = "riposo";
public static final String SPESA = "spesa";
public static final String NOTE = "note";



public static final String[] COLUMNS = {_ID, ENTRATA, DATA, USCITA, BANCA, RIPOSO, NOTE};
```

}

then, I do these tests. Launching the version 1 and then 2 all goes well. but if I cast the only 2 there is a crash.
logcat:

```
 08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bilancio.personale/it.della90.bilancio.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at it.della90.bilancio.db.BilancioHelper.onCreate(BilancioHelper.java:38)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at it.della90.bilancio.MainActivity.calcolaTotaleRisparmioMese(MainActivity.java:342)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at it.della90.bilancio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-18 16:54:15.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     ... 11 more

Comment: Is your table Giornate already created? If its not it wont change it! The ALTER TABLE command needs an existing table so it can be applied on it!

http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: the table already exists, I just have to add a column, but as I said in my first post if the user changes from the old version to the new one everything is working properly, if it is installed only the new version of the column is not created? should I do something else besides alter table?

Comment: If the user installs the new version there is no upgrade for the Database because database doesnt exist! So you have to do the ALTERnation of the table in another way and not inside your onUpgrade!

Comment: ok how?? have not found any documentation about this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use SharedPreferences to check if he uses the new version of your database!

Inside your onCreate method:

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("SYNC_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean flag = shared.getBoolean("new_version_database",true);

if(flag){ 
   //call your query with the ALTER TABLE in it

   shared.edit().putBoolean("new_version_database",false).commit();

}
```

In any other case you will follow your ordinary database upgrade!

Apply your own code style to the above and you are good to go!

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
BilancioHelper.db = db;

//tabella giornate
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("CREATE TABLE {0} (");
builder.append("{1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
builder.append("{2} TEXT,");
builder.append("{3} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
builder.append("{4} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
builder.append("{5} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
builder.append("{6} INTEGER,"); // E' boolean
builder.append("{7} INTEGER");
builder.append("{8} TEXT");
builder.append(");");

db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(builder.toString(),
        GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME, GiornateTable._ID,
        GiornateTable.DATA, GiornateTable.ENTRATA,
        GiornateTable.USCITA, GiornateTable.BANCA, GiornateTable.RIPOSO, GiornateTable.SPESA, GiornateTable.NOTE));
```

Comment: i put this? if (newVersion >=2) {  
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Giornate ADD COLUMN note TEXT");  
           }

Comment: Create another query that will create your database with the extra table you need and call it in the line where i say "//call your query ..."

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my table that exists. I did not understand the operation. this is my existing table where I have to add the column:

Comment: StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
builder.append("CREATE TABLE {0} (");
builder.append("{1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
builder.append("{2} TEXT,");
builder.append("{3} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
builder.append("{4} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
builder.append("{5} REAL DEFAULT 0,");
builder.append("{6} INTEGER,");
builder.append("{7} INTEGER");
builder.append(");");
db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(builder.toString(),
GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME,GiornateTable._ID,
GiornateTable.DATA,GiornateTable.ENTRATA,
GiornateTable.USCITA,GiornateTable.BANCA, GiornateTable.RIPOSO,GiornateTable.SPESA));

Comment: Add your new column too at the above string! And then call db.execSQL();

Comment: Post it to your original Question

Comment: I copied the code you've modified in the 'OnCreate I have to leave the shared preferences? and in 'ONUPGRADE insert ALTER TABLE'. thanks

Comment: Yeah just leave it like that! Accept my answer if it helped you! Thanks!

Comment: I'm starting my emulator, soon see if there are problems

Comment: it seems to be here:boolean flag = shared.getBoolean("new_version_database",true);

Comment: No its on your Helper class!

Comment: ok I removed the shared from the helper class ... and the column is not created.

Comment: You will add the code with the shared preferences at your first activity not in your Helper class mate!

Comment: ok scusa classe ho Inserito Quel codice Nella mia principale, ma scusa Cosa Devo inserire in QUESTE righe?if(flag){ 
       //call your query with the ALTER TABLE in it

      shared.edit().putBoolean("new_version_database",false).commit();